# why am I getting an error when installing RVM (Ruby Version Manager) on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am following a guide to install RVM (ruby version manager) from [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

the first command it tells you to write in the command line is this

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0
```

however it gives the following error.

> 'gpg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

what do I do now? can anyone either help or point to a better explained tutorial. everything i have found assumes a good knowledge of ruby and programming.  There are so few begginners tutorials out there. Everything is geared to advanced programmers who understand all the jargon. I need step by step explanations becasue i am unfamiliar with the processes involved. thanks.

Comment: What operating system you are on?

Comment: _"The basic requirements are `bash`, `curl`, `gpg2` and overall GNU version of tools"_ – seems like you don't have gpg installed.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the program `gpg` couldn't be found. Either, it isn't installed or it isn't in the search path. How to install programs and how to put them on the search path is a basic user question and has nothing to do with programming, therefore is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score -1):

From the error message I'm guessing you're on windows. Please try installing gpg binaries from here https://www.gnupg.org/download/ (table at the bottom)

If you're on Linux, try one of these:

- on ubuntu `sudo apt install curl gpg2`
- on fedora (also CentOS I think) `yum install  -y curl gnupg2`

If you are on a different distro, or os:  generally search for `install gpg2 on [your OS name here]`

Comment: If you can’t really help, you should not post answers. That simple.

Comment: so is this answer wrong. i shouldn't download gpg? could someone please explain what gpg is and why i need it? what is happening when i get this error? and which of thesee should i follow? becasue you gave 2 answers. i am on windows 10.

Comment: There's a full description of what gpg is here: https://www.gnupg.org/index.html and RVM is using this package.

Comment: @Owen this answer is not wrong, did you even try it?